# How to compare 2 different length arrays to eachother

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a function that compares two different length arrays to each other and  if they match then some actions are performed. Array1, cell1 compares to array2, cell1, cell2, cellN... Then Array1, cell2 compares to array2, cell1, cell2, cellN...

Something resembling this:

```
if(array1[$i]==array2[])
{
   // Some actions...
}
```

How can this be implemented?

Comment: Personally I didn't get the point.

Comment: What would constitute a match? If *any* element of array 1 matches *any* element of array 2? If *all* elements of array 1 are also in array 2? Can you post a concrete example of matching and non-matching data?

Comment: How can two arrays with a different length match?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP has `in_array` for searching an array for a particular value. So what about

```
foreach ($array1 as $search_item)
{
    if (in_array($search_item, $array2))
    {
        // Some actions...
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the `$array2` contain any value `2 times` the `some action` will be performed once instead of 2 time

Answer (score 3):

You can get the difference of the Arrays with the PHP function [array_diff](http://php.net/array_diff).

```
<?php
$array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
$array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
$result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Results in

```
Array
(
    [1] => blue
)
```

Comment: I don't need the differing values, I need the values that match

Comment: @Henkka: It matches the values

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested loops for this.

```
for($i=0; $i<count($array1); $i++){
    for($j=0; $j<count($array2); $j++){
        if($array1[$i] == $array2[$j]){
            //some action here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

kindly correct the errors. im comparing the arrays values to display respectively with their paired one

if((cardnumb1[1]==123456789) && (passcode[1]==1234))

```
                         else if ((cardnumb1[2]==987654321) && (passcode[2]==4567))

                         else if ((cardnumb1[3]==123789456) && (passcode[3]==7890))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if answered I think, just for reference, is good to know that you can make:

```
$array_1 = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$array_2 = array(2,4,6,8);

foreach (array_intersect($array_1,$array_2) as $match){
    //do something
}
```

NOTE: may give some problems with associative arrays.